# Modules share the same url when only declared once in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I am writing an app using requirejs. Some of the modules I have written simply load in multiple components for easier access. These modules are causing the following error when I run my app through the requirejs optimizer:

```
The following modules share the same URL. This could be a misconfiguration if that URL only has one anonymous module in it:
F:/nemesis/nemesis/src/nemesis.js: nemesis, nemesis
F:/nemesis/nemesis/src/_nemesis.js: _nemesis, _nemesis
F:/nemesis/nemesis/src/rendering/rendering.js: rendering/rendering, rendering/rendering] }
```

Here is how each module it defined.

**nemesis.js**

```
define(["require", "exports", "_nemesis", 'rendering/rendering'], function(require, exports, _nemesis, Rendering) {
    /* Definition code */
});
```

**_nemesis.js**

```
define(["require", "exports", "json!config.json"], function(require, exports, config) {
    /* Definition code */
});
```

**rendering/rendering.js**

```
define(["require", "exports", "_nemesis", "./shaders", "./primitive", "util/logging/consoleLogger"], function(require, exports, nemesis, Shaders, Render, Logger) {
    /* Definition code */
});
```

And finally this is how I requirejs configured:

```
baseUrl: "src/",
name: "<%= pkg.name %>",
paths: {
    text: "../node_modules/text/text",
    json: "../lib/requirejs-plugins/json",
    "config.json": 'empty'
},
out: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
optimize: 'none'
```

Have a configured or declared the modules wrong or am I missing something in the configuration?

Also, the module declaration we generated from typescript. Could different argument with the typescript compiler fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was with the "config.json" in the paths. Changing it to

```
config: 'empty:'
```

made everything compile as expected. However I am not sure why this caused the error I was getting or why

```
"config.json" : 'empty:'
```

does not work, so I would be grateful if someone could explain that.